# how to post like with facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook-like, facebook-c#-sdk

How do you post a like to a facebook app using the c# sdk ?
I tried with this code:

```
...
FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
Dictionary<string,object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
app.PostAsync(string.Format("{0}/likes", appId), parameters);
...
```

but I get ArgumentNullException: stream cannot be null

Comment: Note that I was able to upload an image and post to the wall using the same token...

Comment: It looks like your dictionary is empty for a start

Comment: what parameter should it contain ?